# Setting up LAMP server, trouble with phpmyadmin "Cannot load or save configuration

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, lamp

I am trying to set up a LAMP server on a Ubuntu 14.04 desktop, but am having trouble with setting up phpmyadmin. It is very similar to this (unanswered) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902872/phpmyadmin-cannot-load-or-save-configuration)

phpmyadmin is located here:

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

I created the config folder as outlined in the [docs](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#setup_script), but when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin I get this error:

```
Directory config, which is used by the setup script, still exists in your phpMyAdmin directory. You should remove it once phpMyAdmin has been configured.
```

Going to localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php will then give me this error:

```
Cannot load or save configuration
Please create web server writable folder config in phpMyAdmin top level directory as described in documentation. Otherwise you will be only able to download or display it.
```

Any ideas on why I can't load the script?

/etc/phpmyadmin has:

```
apache.conf   config.footer.inc.php   htpasswd.setup   phpmyadmin.service 
conf.d        config.header.inc.php   lighttpd.conf
config-db.php config.inc.php          phpmyadmin.desktop
```

Comment: What's in `/etc/phpmyadmin`?

Comment: How did you install it? By deb package or manually?

Comment: @Michelem I did a manual install, as you can tell I don't know much about setting up LAMP servers.

Comment: So you probably still have the `config`directory inside `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`, I'd recommend to trash everything you did and use `apt-get install phpmyadmin` and you are done.

Comment: @Michelem I know hot to take the config directory out, I can't load the script as outlined in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried accessing localhost/phpmyadmin?

Also, try creating a soft link under /var/www/html/ to /usr/share/phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes I can access it fine, the error of `config` still being in the TLD shows that it is there, but going to the setup page from settings shows the second error of `Cannot load or save configuration`. I will try the soft link.

Comment: then you should try purging it and using apt-get install phpmyadmin